# Quick implementation of GUI application that reads local server data

Tags: python, html, user-interface, server, wysiwyg

### The Issue

I'm trying to build a very simple GUI application that either (i) runs on a local Ubuntu 14 server, or (ii) that runs locally but can read/write data from this server. Multiple people will be using this implementation to make modifications to a very simple array data file. The final solution can either be a script, dynamic webpage, or precompiled program.

### Attempted Solutions

- Writing an HTML file that uses PHP to read/write form data: PHP is not enabled on this server. HTML5 FileSystem API doesn't seem to do what I need it to (i.e. it seems to only sandbox IO).
- Python: Tkl/Tcl/wxWidgets are not available on this server, and most of the people who will be using this won't have it available locally either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server should have X11 forwarding. Here is a page with an introduction:

http://math.msu.su/~vvb/2course/Borisenko/CppProjects/GWindow/xintro.html

I don't recommend coding an X11 application from scratch; this will take a very long time. Use an IDE like QT creator or XCode to speed up the process. If coded in C++, the X11 application should not have compatibility issues like you do with Python and PHP.